# Are La-Nina and positive Indian Ocean dipole similar?

Tags: climate, ocean, monsoon

Because in both the cases, the warm water/ increase in temperature is seen on the east side of Africa.  Does not they mean that they carry rain bearing clouds from east of Africa to India, resulting in flood like situation in India. 
Do they differ in any other way,  please let me know if I got them wrong?

Comment: can you show where La Nina puts warm water on the east side of Africa ? It gives warm water on the west side of Pacific. It maybe that La Nina couples with a positive IOD. Otherwise they are not necessarily correlated.

Comment: @gansub,  yes I was wrong, La Nina gives warm water on west side of Pacific. And how are saying that La Nina couples with positive IOD,  is it because of trade winds.

Comment: @user3748888 Usually La Nina couples with Negative IOD. If you think about it the Indian Summer Monsoon(ISM) has westerlies blowing in from east coast of Africa. So assuming La Nina base state if westerlies strengthen you will have upwelling on east coast of Africa and downwelling on Indonesia etc. So negative IOD happens. Reverse for El Nino and positive IOD. Westerlies weaken during El Nino and easterlies strengthen reversing upwelling and downwelling

Answer (score 1):

The [Indian Ocean dipole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Ocean_Dipole) is essentially a measure of the difference in sea surface temperatures between the western and eastern Indian Ocean.

The [El Nino and La Nina](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/ninonina.html) are the opposite phases of the El Nino Southern Oscillation cycle that occurs in the Pacific Ocean.

The only similarity with the Indian Ocean dipole, is that the difference between the sea surface temperature between the central western Pacific Ocean & central eastern Pacific Ocean are measured.